# How to create inner join in django with mongodb?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, inner-join

I use django framework and mongodb database.
I want to show all the customers with all their phones.
What can I do to avoid using your nesting for loop?
How can I do that?

I know that customer information can be obtained through the Foreign key in the phone model, But I want the for loop on the customers table to reduce the number of counter for loop

my models:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Phones(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from Foreign Key for obtain phones any customers as follows:
The second loop is written as follows:

```
{% for phone in customer.phones_set.all %}
    {{phone.phone_number}}
{% endfor %}
```